# Is there a difference between "marking", "configuration" and "state" in Petri nets?

Tags: petri-nets

When finding sources for certain definitions related to Petri nets, I found that there seem to be three ways of referring to "which tokens are located in each place":

- Configuration (e.g. in Sequential Configuration Graph, also referred to as a reachability graph)
- Marking (e.g. initial marking)
- State (e.g. in State Space analysis).

Is there a subtle difference between these terms, or can they all be used for every type of Petri net?

Comment: Welcome! Your comment is kinda redundant since that's what we're looking for in _all_ answers on this site. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For standard Petri nets, *configuration*, *state* and *marking* are the same thing.
The term *marking* is standard. *State* is probably best avoided, as novices may confuse it with *place*.

For extended Petri nets (e.g. timed Petri nets), a configuration may contain more information than just a marking.